# JavaScript `bind` method does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind

The following controller works without problem.

```
 app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.delete = function(){
            bar($scope);
         }
    }]);
```

I tried to make it a little cleaner by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
 app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.delete = bar.bind(null, $scope);
    }]);
```

Unfortunately, this form does not work as expected and `$scope` is always supplied with an old version of $scope in bound method (`bar` here), even after $scope has changed to refer to a different value. What is wrong with it?

## What else?

If I should not use `bind` here, what is the alternative?

Comment: What's inside Util? I can't think on why would you need to do this.

Comment: Seems a misuse of bind to me.

Comment: Is the problem that a value *is* being supplied to `$scope.delete`, but it's an *old* value? Or is the function just totally failing (or not being supplied a value at all)?

Comment: @ShawnErquhart What makes you think so?

Comment: @apsillers "…changes in  $scope is not send to binded method (bar here)."

Comment: @zeroflagL he's using it for code cleanliness, not for explicitly defining 'this'.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Defining a value for `this` is not the only valid use case. After all it's called `bind`, not `setThisArg`.

Comment: @PHPst Please modify this post to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The behaviour that you describes is the expected for me, because you are removeing the CLOSURE of that method with bind(null...)
I know I'm not helping a lot, but I would recommend to check how the reference objects are passed in Javascript, how works the closure in Javascript, and what the method bind does.
I guess after that you will understand exactly why the $context is not being updated 
Tip: Without closure that var is not related with the method anymore.

Comment: What are you trying to do with scope before calling `delete`? I'm specifically interested in the properties you are setting. Would you share some code, or pseudocode illustrating the case?

Comment: "after $scope has changed to refer to a different value".  Are you actually binding `$scope` to a different value (i.e. `$scope = {};`)?  In that case `delete` will still be curried with whatever the value of `$scope` was at execution.  If you need the value at call time, you'll need to keep the wrapping function. If only a property of `$scope` is changing, then `delete` should read the current value at call time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that your problem is that your bound `Util.bar` is always supplied with an old version of `$scope`, even after `$scope` has changed to refer to a different value.

`bind` binds *values*, not variables. You are binding the *current value of `$scope`* to `Util.bar`. On the other hand, your first style forces the identifier `$scope` to be resolved to a value (or, really, outer-scope variable record) every time the function runs.

If `$scope` changes to refer to a completely different value, you must use the first form. `.bind(null, $scope)` will resolve `$scope` to a value immediately and use that value forever, while the first form without `bind` will resolve `$scope` to a value every time the function runs.

Comment: Thanks, What is the alternative method for the second codes.

Comment: @PHPst The alternative is what you're already doing in your first example. Can you edit to explain why that is not sufficient?

Comment: as @apsillers said in `bind` $scope gets resolved and gets used in subsequent calls cleaner way is first but still want bind then use this app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.delete = function(){ bar.bind(null, $scope); }
    }]);

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yk3ep6gPVsRMAVgpbfR2?p=preview) .

```
   $scope.delete1 = function(){
      bar($scope);
   };

   $scope.delete2 = bar.bind(null, $scope);

   $scope.delete3 = function(){
      bar(this);
   };
```

To me it seems to behave exactly as it should: delete1 and delete2 seem to do the same thing on both parent and child controller. Delete 3 behaves differently - the reason is explained very nicely in this answer: [controller's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/3927379)

Maybe you can specify exactly which behaviour(usecase) you find wrong. The go back links are so that you can leave the controller page and  then come back to new instance of controller(and a new scope - as you can see from $scope.$id).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `bar` doesn't use anything from `Util`? Do this:

```
app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.delete = Util.bar.bind(Util, $scope);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in apsillers answer above, the bind method is being immediately evaluated upon assignment - so $scope's current value is bound as the argument to pass to the bar function. As far as a 'cleaner' alternative, I don't see why you need something 'cleaner': you're looking to assign $scope.delete as a function that invokes bar with the current $scope value, which your current code does to a T. If you're still searching for something a bit leaner code wise you could always adopt ES6 fat arrow syntax (but you'd need a transpiler like babel)- so your code would look like:

```
app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.delete = () => bar($scope);
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

as @apsillers said, in bind $scope gets resolved and gets used in subsequent calls,so cleaner way is the first one but still If you want to use bind then use

```
app.controller('foo', ['$scope',function ($scope) { 
     $scope.delete = function(){ 
         bar.bind(null, $scope); 
     }
}]);
```

Comment: When `delete` is called it just creates a function value that is thrown away.